# In iOS 10+, is there ANY way to RELIABLY wake up an app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, cbperipheral, cbcentralmanager

*I have been at this over 3 months and pulling my hair out. So please don't respond with beginner answers.*

### I am wondering if, in 2017 with iOS 10+, there is ANY way possible to wake up the app from terminated state... preferably by bluetooth peripheral... but i'll take what I can get!

I consider terminated to be when *user swiped the app in task manager or when the peripheral is turned on/off and the app was already dead*

I need important health related BT peripheral data (recorded by BT device)  maintained in the app so I need a consistent connection or the ability to wake the app back up and handle the data. I know this is asked a lot so I am trying to find the most current understanding or solutions to this problem. I have read sooo many articles and S.O. posts on this so I know Core Bluetooth is un-reliable at best. I know the general concept is flaky and people have been saying since 2010 its not possible. However, lots keeps changing in iOS so I was hoping something would have changed.

***To be clear:***

BT wake up would be great but it's really not been reliable, so... I will take ANY kind of reliable wake up (location, audio, BT, etc... NOT iBeacon though since I am connected/paired to BT device). If I have to "hack" the wake up to happen on location or audio and then quickly get the data from the peripheral somehow, I will take it!

### I have tried:

*(SKIP THIS IF YOU DON'T CARE OR IS NOT APPLICABLE)*

---

- Background central mode turned on in info.plist
- Using full state restoration, that is to say, this code...

  ```
  self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                                             queue:nil
                                                               options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey: @(YES),
                                                                         CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"MyDevice"}];
  ```

  To register the identifier key and this code...

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
      NSLog(@"launch options found: %@", launchOptions);
      NSArray *centralManagerIdentifiers = launchOptions[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsBluetoothCentralsKey];

      NSLog(@"central managers found in launch options: %@", centralManagerIdentifiers);
      [self triggerLocalNotification:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"central managers found in launch options: %@", centralManagerIdentifiers]];

      if([centralManagerIdentifiers count] > 0) {
          for(NSString *identifier in centralManagerIdentifiers) {
              if([identifier isEqualToString:@"MyDevice"]) {
                  [self triggerLocalNotification:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Identifier found: %@", identifier]];
                  self.bluetoothManager = [BluetoothMgr sharedInstance];
              }
          }
      }

      return YES;
  }

  - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
    willRestoreState:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)state {

      NSLog(@"************** RESTORED STATE BT **************");
      [self triggerCustomLocalNotification:@"************** RESTORED STATE BT **************"];

      NSLog(@"central manager object: %@", central);
      NSLog(@"state dictionary: %@", state);

      [self triggerCustomLocalNotification:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"state dictionary: %@", state]];


      NSArray *restoredPeripherals = [state objectForKey:@"CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey"];

      self.centralManager = central;
      self.centralManager.delegate = self;

      if([restoredPeripherals count] > 0) {
          for(CBPeripheral *peripheral in restoredPeripherals) {
              if([peripheral.name rangeOfString:@"mybox-"].location != NSNotFound) {
                  NSLog(@"Restoring mybox Box: %@", peripheral);
                  [self triggerCustomLocalNotification:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Peripheral was found in WILL RESTORE STATE! it was: %@", peripheral]];

                  self.myPeripheral = peripheral;
                  self.myPeripheral.delegate = self;

                  [self connectToDevice];

                  return;
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  To restore the central manager state. This only works when the app is killed by iOS or the state is changed. Does not work when the user kills the app.
- Subscribing to a notifying characteristic in the device (I made this custom characteristic and I have full control over the programming of the device) ... this works really well but does not always wake the app up. Works well in background though. Just not terminated.
- Trying to disconnect completely upon termination so that I can use iBeacon to wake back up... too many hoops and in the end it does not work reliably at all.
- Significant location updates... extremely unreliable
- Audio recording... no methods fire when it begins recording (that I could find anyway) or methods that fire intermittently while recording

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally solved this problem! The solution was to use 2 Bluetooth chips in my solution. One chip to be a dedicated BT-Connected Paired/Auth/Bonded device and the other to be a dedicated iBeacon advertiser. With this solution I was able to both, wake up the app whenever I want (by power cycling the iBeacon chip at will) and connecting for BT encryption required characteristics.

Using the `didEnterRegion` method of the `CLLocationManager` class, in the background, I can start up the bluetooth manager... connect to the device in the background and then retrieve data successfully over a previously paired connection.

**UPDATE:** as a side note, it's good to mention that while the iBeacon is fairly reliable in waking up the application in the background, only the `didEnterRegion` method happens immediately when the iBeacon is found or turned on. The `didExitRegion` method takes me (on average) about 30 seconds to fire after I turn off the iBeacon or it is no longer in range.

Comment: @GoraDefex  I need your help. Please look my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813624/re-connect-bluetooth-device-when-app-is-terminated

Comment: @GoreDefex Please look at the question. I also need answer to the same : stackoverflow.com/questions/47813624